# How do I disable a button in a table dynamically?

Tags: angular

[image]

In the above table screenshot, I want to disable the **Approve** button once the user is Approved (i.e, the button is slid to right).
The button on click calls an API which updates is_confirm filed (boolean type) in DB and the same field is being used for disabling the button.
But the button is not getting disabled, it can still be slid.

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
    <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.occupation }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.maritalStatus }}</td>
    <td>{{ user.mobileNo }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn"(click)="viewUserDetails(user.id)"><i class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="user.isConfirm" [checked]="user.isConfirm" (change)="approveUserById(user.id)">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"><button class="btn" (click)="lockOrUnlockUserById(user)"><i [ngClass]="user.isLock ? 'fa fa-unlock fa-lg' : 'fa fa-lock fa-lg'" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

```
Component.ts

//Method to get all the users called in onInit

  viewUsersList(roleId: string) {
    
    let cityObj = {roleId:roleId,cityId:this.selectedCity}
    
    this.httpClient.post('USER_LIST_API', cityObj).subscribe(
        (responseData: any) => {
          this.users = <ViewUser[]>responseData
          console.log("Response Data: ",responseData)
          console.log(this.users)
        },
        (error: any) => {
          console.log(error)
          this.router.navigate(['error']);
        }
      )
  }

  //Method to approve a user

  approveUserById(userId: string) {

    this.httpClient.post('APPROVE_USER_API', userId).subscribe(
      (responseData: any) => {
        if (responseData.message === 'TRUE') {
            
            //*This is the place I need help to refresh the data *
          console.log("Response ",responseData)
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: Is this component implements `onPush` strategy? Can you post the component .ts please?

Comment: @RazRonen No, I am not using ```onPush``` (I am a newbie to angular, I don't know about ```onPush```). I have added my component.ts file.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[disabled]="!user.isConfirm"**

````
 <input type="checkbox" [disabled]="!user.isConfirm" [checked]="user.isConfirm" (change)="approveUserById(user.id)">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try: `<button [disabled]="!is_confirm" ...>`

Comment: Please consider explaining how and why this solves the problem, so that it can benefit other users too.